# Set session when on boot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm new to Laravel and am trying to set a session of users country of origin when they hit any page on my website.

in the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` I added this

```
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   */
  public function boot(Request $request): void
  {
    
    //get user geolocation
    (new Controller)->geoLocation($request);

  }
```

in my `App\Http\Controllers\Controllers.php`

```
public function geoLocation(Request $request) {

....
...
...
if (!$request->session()->has('country_code')) {
  ....
  ....
}

}
```

when i run `php artisan serv` i get this error `Session store not set on request.`

any idea what i'm doing wrong or how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any code that is related to setting session

Comment: @MohammadSalehi it says `app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php:32` and line 32 is this `if (!$request->session()->has('country_code'))` tho

Comment: Isn't it just checking to see if the session `country_code` exists? how did you set it?

Comment: if session doesn't exist i set it in the if statement like this `$request->session()->put('country_code', 'us');`

Comment: i just replaced `$request->session()` with `session()` and it worked fine.